# Save value from custom hook to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to save a value from a custom hook, which is fetching data for the server, to functional component state with useState, because I later need to change this value and after the change it needs to rerender. So desired behaviour is:

1. Set State variable to value from custom hook
2. Render stuff with this state variable
3. Modify state on button click
4. Rerender with new state

What I tried is:

- Set the inital value of useState to my hook:
  `const [data, setData] = useState<DataType[] | null>(useLoadData(id).data)`
  but then data is always empty.
- Set the state in a useEffect() hook:

  ```
  useEffect(()=>{
      const d = useLoadData(id).data
      setData(d)
  }, [id])
  ```

  But this is showing me the Error warning:  Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
- Doing this:

  ```
  const [data, setData] = useState<DocumentType[]>([])
  const dataFromServer = useLoadData(id).data

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (dataFromServer){
      setData(dataFromServer)
    }
  }, [dataFromServer])
  ```

  Leading to:  ERROR: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

What would be a proper solution for my use case?

Comment: Option 3 is what you should target. How often do you need to load the data from the `useLoadData` hook? Can you share that implementation?

Comment: @Steffi: If your question is answered, please accept the answer. That helps the broader community to find the right answer to a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your custom hook returns a new array every time it is used.

**Solution 1**: change your hook to return a 'cached' instance of an array.

```
function useLoadData(id) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData(id).then(setData);
  }, [id]);

  // good
  return data;

  //bad
  //return data.map(...)

  //bad
  //return data.filter(...)

  //etc
}
```

[codesandbox.io link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-2ytqi?file=/index.js)

**Solution 2**: change your hook to accept `setData` as a parameter.

```
function useLoadData(id, setData) {
  useEffect(() => {
    loadData(id).then(setData);
  }, [id]);
}
```

Here I am telling the hook where to store data so that both custom hook and a button in a component can write to a same place.

[codesandbox.io link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-m754q?file=/index.js)

Full example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// simulates async data loading
function loadData(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, [id, id, id]));
}

// a specialized 'stateless' version of custom hook
function useLoadData(id, setData) {
  useEffect(() => {
    loadData(id).then(setData);
  }, [id]);
}

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useLoadData(123, setData);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Data: {data == null ? "Loading..." : data.join()}</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setData([456, 456, 456])}>Change data</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```